# complex data type implementation over joined data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have joined data from two tables and I want to convert this into a complex data type (`Map`).

```
// creating data frame of product data file
val proDF = spark.read.format("parquet").load("path")

// creating data frame of Finance data file
val finDF = spark.read.format("parquet").load("path")

// joining both the data frames
val proFinJoinDF = proDF.joinWith(finDF, proDF("col1") === finDF("col1") && proDF("col2") === finDF("col2") && proDF("col3") === finDF("col3"))

// saving joined data into temporary table 
proFinJoinDF.registerTempTable("join_Data")

val new1 = spark.sql("""select 
_1.col1 as A,
_1.col2 as B,...
_2.col1 as P,
_2.col2 as Q,
_2.col3 as R... from join_data""" )

// to convert data type to "string" for Map
var strnew1 = new1.select(new1.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)) : _*)

// creating case class for Map type 
case class Pro_Fin(A: String, B: String, ProMap: Map[String, String], FinMap: Map[String, String])
```

Now I want to convert my joined data into above case class (`Pro_Fin`) and save it into the table.

Expected output:

```
A   B   proMap<c:value, d:value …>  finMap<P:value, Q:value …>
```

Comment: What is your input data? What does the data format currently look like in strnew1? What strings are you trying to put in which Map? Please provide necessary details to answer this question.

Comment: in your select statemet ise collect_list and map function to create your maps and use .as[pro_fin] at the end to cast it to your case class

Comment: @JonathanMyers 
`scala> var strnew1 = new1.select(new1.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(StringType)) : _*)

strnew1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [unique_id: string, Product_Id: string ... 196 more fields]`

there are two tables so i want to create separate map for both the input table into a single table. as mentioned in expected output where A B are my keys and proMap and finMap are my complex data type so there will be 4 columns in final table.